# How to use Promise or Async for parallel drawing in GetUserMedia frame to simulate heavy process?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, getusermedia, requestanimationframe

What I am looking for is to get webcam feed using GetUserMedia and then in Process loop draw something with two functions in parallel. I have arbitrary delay in both of the drawing functions in order to simulate heavy process.

I have tried with following code.

In this code, I have one video object denoted as 'video' and two canvases one is 'input' and another is 'output' and their contexts are 'ctxInput', 'ctxOutput' respectively.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment", width: 320, height: 240 } }).then(stream => {        
        if ("srcObject" in video) {
            video.onplaying = function () {
                function processVideo() {
                    ctxInput.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
                    var imgData = ctxInput.getImageData(0, 0, canvasInput.width, canvasInput.height);
                    ctxOutput.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
                    Promise.all([drawTestLineR(ctxOutput), drawTestLineG(ctxOutput)]).then(e => { 
                        requestAnimationFrame(processVideo);
                    });
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(processVideo);
            }
            video.srcObject = stream;
        }
}).catch(e => { console.log(e); });
    
function wait(milisec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve('') }, milisec);
  })
}
function drawTestLineR(context) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        wait(100).then(e => {
            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle = 'red';
            context.lineWidth = 4;
            context.moveTo(0, 0);
            context.lineTo(50, 50);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
            context.restore();
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
function drawTestLineG(context) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        wait(150).then(e => {
            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle = 'green';
            context.lineWidth = 4;
            context.moveTo(50, 50);
            context.lineTo(100, 100);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
            context.restore();
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

But problem with this is the red line is blinking and the green line is not getting drawn,  at all. Also I have tried to use Async-Await but problem remain same. Not sure but it looks like some frames are getting skipped.

**Edit:**

For better understanding of my query I am attaching two codepen examples.

Please look at these two codepen.

1. Sync: https://codepen.io/smithangshu/full/BaRGyVw
2. Async(Promise All): https://codepen.io/smithangshu/full/MWmzYJX

In sync I am getting delay between each frames drawing 250 ms. Because drawing function for red line waits for 100 ms before drawing and drawing function for green line waits for 150 ms before drawing. So all together total waiting time is (100 ms + 150 ms) = 250 ms. But as you can see line are always visible in output canvas.

But in Async(Promise All) what I expect is delay of max(100 ms, 150 ms) = 150 ms and the output canvas would reflect same result as Sync operation(always visible red and green line).

Hope this would clear my query.

Comment: How long do you expect the red and green lines to be visible? Can you describe exactly on a time line what you want to see on `ctxOutput` at each stage of the time progression? Like `(0 - 50): nothing, (50-100): red line, (100-150): both red and green lines, (150-200): image, ...etc`

Comment: Basically, what I am looking for it should be visible always. In terms of timeline,

Comment: If you want the lines visible always, then I don't understand why you don't draw them immediately, instead of waiting for a while. Can you edit your question, and make *very* clear what the sequence of operations should be on a time line?

Comment: Basically, what I am looking for it should be visible always. Just like if I would use these drawing functions Synchronously only difference would be when sync way it would take 100+150 =250ms and when in async(promise.all) way it would take max(100,150)=150ms.

Comment: Because I need to simulate two heavy functions to draw which would take 100ms and 150ms respectively that's why can not draw immediately just after drawing the frame.

Comment: What does that mean? That the line is drawn progressively somehow? Currently you do wait + draw. But if you want the line to be visible all the time, you should do draw + wait, right? Is it that what you are asking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235730/discussion-between-smithangshu-ghosh-and-trincot).